# Why does this throw Concurrent Modification Exception

Tags: java

The following code works fine when there are more than one modification in a particular map. But when there is only one modification it throws concurrent modification exception

```
for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> mapEntry : beanMap.entrySet()) {
    for(String dateSet : dateList) {
        String mName = mapEntry.getKey();
        boolean dateFound = false;
        if(beanMap.containsKey(dateSet)) {
            dateFound = true;
            System.out.println("    Found : "+mapEntry.getKey());
        }
        if(!dateFound)
        {
            Map<String, List<String>> modifiedMap = beanMap;
            List<String> newBeanList = new ArrayList<String>();
            dBean beanData = new Bean(dateSet+"NA","NA","NA",0,0,0);
            newBeanList.add(beanData);
            System.out.println("    Adding : "+dateSet+" "+"NA");
            modifiedMap.put(mName, newBeanList);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code it throws ConcurrentModificationException when modifying the "modifiedMap" only once. May be there is more to it but couldn't find out why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use an enhanced `for` loop, there is an implicit `Iterator` working behind the scenes.  You attempt to make a copy of `beanMap` with this line:

```
Map<String, List<String>> modifiedMap = beanMap;
```

However, this only creates another reference variable that also refers to the same map object.  There is still only one map, and you are modifying it:

```
modifiedMap.put(mName, newBeanList);
```

The `Iterator` then detects that the map is modified when it attempts to iterate to the next entry, resulting in the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

You can create another `Map` with `new`, and `put` all your modifications into that map while you're iterating the original map.

After you're done iterating the original map, you can call [the `putAll` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll-java.util.Map-) on it, passing your new map, to apply all of the modifications you want.

Comment: Or use the Iterator in for loop like this
Iterator<Entry<String, List<Bean>>> iterator = beanMap.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); 

Which is better?

Comment: Another option is to create a copy of the original when you start your iterator  e.g. for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> mapEntry : new ArrayList(beanMap.entrySet()))

Comment: @user1629109 Even if you use an explicit `Iterator`, it can still throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` when you modify the map.  The key here is to avoid modifying the map as you're iterating over it with an `Iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to change the underlying collection while iterating over it using this syntax. The collections are implemented in a fail-fast way, so even a single change will raise the exception.

If you need to change the collection while visiting the elements, use an `Iterator`.

Comment: Can you pls add the relevant change in the code specified in OP?

Answer (score 0):

`modifiedMap`  is the reference to same Map `beanMap` on which you are iterating. You are modifying the Collection `modifiedMap` while iteration hence the Exception.

Comment: I agree. I knew that was going on. But what would be the solution. I can't create a new instance of modifiedMap.

Comment: Well many workarounds. One way is that do a deep copy of your map and modify that.